# Special characters show as question marks in the shell

Tags: raspbian, bash

I installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi B+ on an ext2/ext3 file system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux pi 3.18.0-trunk-rpi #1 PREEMPT Debian 3.18.5-1~exp1+rpi16 (2015-03-28) armv6l GNU/Linux
$ stat -f -c %T /
ext2/ext3
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have some music files on my SD card. There are some special characters that don't show well:

```
$ ls
01 - Nocturne op 48 ?? Mademoiselle Laude Duperr?? N 1.mp3  06 - Nocturne op 27 ?? la comtesse d Appony N 1.mp3
02 - Nocturne op 48 ?? Mademoiselle Laude Duperr?? N 2.mp3  07 - Nocturne op 27 ?? la comtesse d Appony N 2.mp3
03 - Nocturne op 15 ?? Monsieur F Hiller N 1.mp3            08 - Nocturne op 20 en ut di??se mineur.mp3
04 - Nocturne op 15 ?? Monsieur F Hiller N 2.mp3            09 - Nocturne op 32 ?? la baronne de Billing N 1.mp3
05 - Nocturne op 15 ?? Monsieur F Hiller N 3.mp3
```

I have a Debian machine where this works just fine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zenbook 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1 (2015-05-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ stat -f -c %T /
ext2/ext3
$ locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
$ ls
01 - Nocturne op 48 à Mademoiselle Laude Duperré N 1.mp3  06 - Nocturne op 27 à la comtesse d Appony N 1.mp3
02 - Nocturne op 48 à Mademoiselle Laude Duperré N 2.mp3  07 - Nocturne op 27 à la comtesse d Appony N 2.mp3
03 - Nocturne op 15 à Monsieur F Hiller N 1.mp3           08 - Nocturne op 20 en ut dièse mineur.mp3
04 - Nocturne op 15 à Monsieur F Hiller N 2.mp3           09 - Nocturne op 32 à la baronne de Billing N 1.mp3
05 - Nocturne op 15 à Monsieur F Hiller N 3.mp3
```

What might be the cause of this? The Debian installation is slightly newer, but surely that shouldn't matter? Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joan helped me find the right page. The locales weren't configured properly. I did:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It showed a list where I selected `en_US.utf8`. It then generated the locales. Both the `locale` warnings and the question marks are gone.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have different fonts loaded on your Debian and Raspbian machines.

Try the fc-list command on your Debian and Raspbian machines and check for differences.

See https://wiki.debian.org/Fonts

Comment: I'm accessing the Raspberry Pi through SSH on my Debian machine - then this shouldn't matter, right? In any case I'll check.

Comment: In any case, DejaVu Sans Mono is the only monospace font on the Raspbian machine and it has these special characters ([charmap](http://www.fontspace.com/dejavu/dejavu-sans-mono/20940.charmap)).

Comment: @CamilStaps Oh well, to me that was the obvious thing to check.